# javascript matching mismatch

Tags: regex, hostname

I have a problem with following pattern:

```
^(?=.{1,255}$)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

i don't want to match : host..com

Please Help me ....

Regards
 AMIR

Comment: and what do you want to match?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{1,61}` contains `.` and can be repeated 61 times, here's your problem. As a side note, there's no need to escape `.` in character classes and it looks like you've got an extra `-`.

Comment: And what about `host--com` or `host-.com`?

Comment: Thank you so much Roman ... it worked ..

Comment: @AmirHelforush: What worked?

Comment: these are fine .... but i have new problem with continue of string                                new pattern =  ^(?=.{1,255}$)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-].{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$                        example ----> not match "host.com.com"

Comment: Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/pcVG5J/1).

Comment: Wow , Thank you so much Wiktor .... it is perfect for me ...

Comment: another problem ... by this pattern , i want to match "host" without DOT